# Why do I keep getting syntax error in insert into (MS Access 2013)

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I am new to SQL.  I want to add lines to a table without creating duplicates, but I keep getting errors and I don't know why:

```
INSERT INTO [P ET FA] (id_danger, P, FA)
    (SELECT 
         measure.id_danger, SUM(mesure.valeur_mesure) AS P, SUM(mesure.Val) AS FA
     FROM mesure
     GROUP BY mesure.id_danger)
WHERE mesure.id_danger != [P ET FA].id_danger
```

Comment: 1.  Include the actual SQL as text, not an image.
2.  Indicate the variant of SQL you're using (TSQL, Oracle, MySQL, etc.)

Fix your post or it will be deleted.    In the meantime, you have inserted with a where clause that implies a join between the source and destination table (without there being an actual join).     Almost all popular SQLs can do this, but the syntax differs from platform to platform.

Comment: Alright, now look at the error message its returning.  What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with ACCESS but you could try:

```
INSERT INTO [P ET FA] (id_danger, P, FA)
SELECT measure.id_danger, SUM(mesure.valeur_mesure) AS P, SUM(mesure.Val) AS FA
FROM mesure
where mesure.id_danger not in (select id_danger FROM [P ET FA])
GROUP BY mesure.id_danger
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [P ET FA] (id_danger, P, FA)
   SELECT SRC.id_danger, 
          SUM(SRC.valeur_mesure) AS P, 
          SUM(SRC.val) AS FA 
     FROM mesure SRC
          LEFT JOIN [P ET FA] DEST
            ON SRC.id_danger = DEST.id_danger
     WHERE DEST.id_danger IS NULL
           GROUP BY SRC.id_danger
```

This will insert values ONLY for those id_danger values that are not already in the destination table.